# Starting vnc-server with command every startup in linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, vnc-server

I run a headless Kali Linux raspberry pi.
I got the ssh to work properly and start at boot.
I got the vnc working but only when I start it manually from terminal.

Problem:
I need to start the vnc-server every time the raspberry boots.
And I have tried like a 100 different things from google but this seems to be the "most" successful for me.

I have created a .sh file with this content:

File path: **/root/Documents/startavnc.sh**

```
x11vnc -gui -display :0 -usepw -rfbport 5900 -bg
```

This code works when I run it directly in terminal.

I have then created this file:

**/etc/init.d/startavnc**

With the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          startavnc
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $network $time
# Should-Stop:       $network $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start and stops the vnc-server
# Description:       Controls the automatic start of vnc-server at reboot
### END INIT INFO
/root/Documents/startavnc.sh
```

I took these LBG-stuff from another file and I'm not sure if I need all. But I got some errors when they where not included so I added them.

I then ran:

**chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/startavnc
update-rc.d startavnc defaults**

When it didn't work I googled some more and ran:

**ln -s /etc/init.d/startavnc /etc/rc.d**

And it still aren't executing when I boot up the pi.

Can you see some obvious fault in this?
I'm, as you probably already figured, a Linux newbie...

Thanks!

Comment: `init.d`? Don't you have `systemctl` on your raspberry-pi? What system are you running?

Comment: @KamilCuk Well, that I don't know. I run Kali Linux re4son. But if i have `systemctl`, how do I use it for this purpose? Thanks!

Comment: I usually do something similar to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC#Starting_and_stopping_vncserver_via_systemd).